# Why it return false?hashCode also equal

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to solve this but it returns false. HashCode and data in both literal is the same if

```
String s1="java";
String s2="JAVA".toLowerCase();
System.out.println(s1==s1);
```

[image: Reference image]

Comment: at the end, perhaps s1==s2

Comment: s1.equals(s2) will return true as it compares the value or content of the string. and for `==` will compare the memory location value not the content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java

Answer (score 1):

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
         String s1="java";
        String s2="JAVA".toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(s1.hashCode());
        System.out.println(s1.hashCode());
        System.out.println(s1==s2);
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
     }
}
```

[image: Output]

`.equals()` will compare the value of variables.

`==` will compare the value of variable memory locations.

`Hashcode` is calculated based on the content of the string and not the location of string.

As you are using `String class`, it is of reference type 
find documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: @akshayraut  if you find the above answer helpful kindly respond it as accepted.

Comment: Hello String s1="java";
String s2="java" and use s1==s2 then it return true.but see in above example there s2="JAVA".toLowerCase(); here also s2 store "java"(I print s2 on console) so why it return false.